# Ошибка при запуске activity null object reference

Tags: android

При нажатии на кнопку должна запускаться другая активность. Однако возникает следующая ошибка:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.diploma10, PID: 11304
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.diploma10/com.example.diploma10.Parameters_of_user}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:145)
        at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:131)
        at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:6510)
        at com.example.diploma10.Parameters_of_user.<init>(Parameters_of_user.java:17)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:41)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1243)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3182)
```

Полный код Paramenters_of_user:

```
package com.example.diploma10;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

public class Parameters_of_user extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_parameters_of_user);

        setTitle("Настройки");

        Button button_list = findViewById(R.id.id_button_subscription_list);

        // создаем обработчик нажатия
        OnClickListener oclBtnList = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent k = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Subscription_list.class);
                startActivity(k);
            }
        };

        button_list.setOnClickListener(oclBtnList);

        BottomNavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomID);
        navigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_parameters_of_user);

        navigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                switch (menuItem.getItemId())
                {
                    case R.id.nav_news:
                        Intent a = new Intent(Parameters_of_user.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(a);
                        //selectedFragment = new Timetable();
                        break;

                    case R.id.nav_parameters_of_user:
                        Intent b = new Intent(Parameters_of_user.this, Parameters_of_user.class);
                        startActivity(b);
                        //selectedFragment = new TeachersList();
                        break;

                    case R.id.nav_email:
                        Intent c = new Intent(Parameters_of_user.this, Mail.class);
                        startActivity(c);
                        //selectedFragment = new Settings();
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Полный код Subscription_list:

```
package com.example.diploma10;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Subscription_list extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_subscription_list);

        setTitle("Список подписок");

        ArrayList news = new ArrayList();

        news.add("Подписка 1");
        news.add("Подписка 2");
        news.add("Подписка 3");

        final ListView NewsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_news_id);

        // создаем адаптеры
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, news);

        // присваиваем адаптер списку
        NewsList.setAdapter(adapter);

        BottomNavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomID);
        navigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_news);
    }
}
```

Comment: Эту строчку `Intent k = new Intent(Parameters_of_user.this, Subscription_list.class);` (которая вне метода `onClick`) удалите

Comment: Это не помогло, проблема осталась та же

Comment: `Parameters_of_user.java:17` - эта строка случайно не здесь `setTitle("Настройки");` ?

Comment: Попробуйте тогда вместо `Parameters_of_user.this` использовать `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov, может лучше будет `this` просто использовать?

Comment: @Andrew `this` вроде можно использовать только после `setContentView`, тут это выполняется, конечно, но я вообще больше не вижу причин для возникновения ошибки, вот и хочу проверить

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov, возможно проблема в том что не сетится слушатель нажатий на кнопку, либо он сетится но это не выложили в вопрос. Но вообще ошибок я не вижу больше критичных так же как и вы :)

Comment: @Ульяна, вы сетите слушатель нажатий кнопки к самой кнопке? у вас есть строка типа этой `button.setOnClickListener(oclBtnList );`?

Comment: @Andrew да, так делаю

Comment: 17 строка где находится?

Comment: @Andrew после `public void onClick(View v) {`

Comment: @Ульяна а приведите полный код класса `Parameters_of_user`, пожалуйста

Comment: `Intent k = new Intent(Parameters_of_user.this, Subscription_list.class);` - здесь? если да то покажите вторую активность

Comment: @Andrew добавила код в описание к вопросу

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov добавила код в описание к вопросу

Comment: ошибка возникает при нажатии на кнопку, так?

Comment: попробуйте вместо `getApplicationContext` поставить просто `this`

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov да

Comment: Проверьте, пожалуйста, на какой именно строке происходит падение. Это можно сделать с помощью точек останова, либо логов и logcat. Падение происходит внутри метода `onClick`, нужно только понять на какой из двух строк.

Comment: @Andrew при использовании this возникает такая ошибка: error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(<anonymous OnClickListener>,Class<Subscription_list>)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to String)
constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context)

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov падение происходит на строчке `startActivity(k);`

Comment: Наиболее правильным будет, все же, использование `Parameters_of_user.this`. И скажите пожалуйста, Вы используете эмулятор, или реальное устройство? Если реальное устройство, то какое?

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov я использую эмулятор

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По итогам исследования кода автора с гита, ошибки найдены:

1. Класс `Subscription_list` строка 28, было:

   ```
   final ListView NewsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_news_id);
   ```

   Должно стать:

   ```
   final ListView NewsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.id_subscription_list);
   ```

   Пояснение: использован неправильный `id` из файла разметки
2. Файл *activity_subscription_list.xml* забыли добавить используемый в коде `BottomNavigationView`. Этот файл разметки должен выглядеть так:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Subscription_list">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/id_subscription_list"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="729dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomID"
        android:layout_width="416dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="622dp"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

После внесения указанных правок проект запустился без ошибок, функция открытия активности по нажатию кнопки отработала хорошо:)

Comment: К сожалению, это не помогло

Comment: @Ульяна у Вас проект на гите есть? Потому что у меня больше идей никаких не осталось, было бы интересно взглянуть самому и попробовать запустить

Comment: вот: https://github.com/ulianabel128/diploma10.git

Comment: @Ульяна ответ подкорректировал, у меня теперь все работает, проверяйте)

Comment: большое спасибо, все заработало!